# How to debug "py2neo.database.status.ConstraintViolationException: Constraint already exists" in flaskr and neo4j?

Tags: python, neo4j

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 1, in <module>
    from blog import app
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\py2neo\neo4j-flask\blog\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    graph.schema.create_uniqueness_constraint("User", "username")
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\py2neo\neo4j-flask\venv\lib\site-packages\py2neo\database\__init__.py", line 775, in create_uniqueness_constraint
    {"property_keys": [property_key]})
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\py2neo\neo4j-flask\venv\lib\site-packages\py2neo\database\http.py", line 212, in post
    raise_from(GraphError(message, **content), error)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\py2neo\neo4j-flask\venv\lib\site-packages\py2neo\util.py", line 124, in raise_from
    raise exception
py2neo.database.status.ConstraintViolationException: Constraint already exists: CONSTRAINT ON ( user:User ) ASSERT user.username IS UNIQUE
```

Comment: I think the error in this one is pretty clear: you're attempting to add a constraint on the db that already exists. Constraints and indexes only need to be created once, and they should not be a part of any scripts which are meant to run repeatedly. Even when you're talking about data population scripts, it's best to separate out index and constraint creation to its own script so it won't interfere if you try to reload data into the same db later.

Comment: so what do I need to do to fix it, remove code        graph.schema.create_uniqueness_constraint("User", "username")?

Comment: I would assume so. That code should never appear in a script you intend to run more than once.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have already delete the constraint create code and it worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid that `ConstraintViolationException`, you can use the APOC procedure [apoc.schema.assert](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_schema) to ensure that all the "schema" (indexes and constraints) you require exist.

- If any schema specified in the call do not already exist, they are created.
- **But be aware that any pre-existing schema that are NOT specified in the call will be dropped.**

There is an example of how to use `apoc.schema.assert` in the middle of [this section of the APOC documentation](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_cassandra_example).